# Installing Pi-hole in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

Hey I'm trying to install and use pi-hole on ubuntu 20.04.

I've tried it many times , and I've also tried docker. Please help me to use pi-hole on ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The install is very straightforward. You don't need docker at all. If the system you are using is dedicated to pi-hole, then I would recommend another clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for cleanness-sake. If you don't want to, that's fine. I don't think it will be an issue.

All you have to do is run the command `curl -sSL https://install.pi-hole.net | sudo bash`. This is their one-step install process. Please notice the `sudo` part. Administrative privileges are needed in order for the installation to work. After all the software has been installed, the install will prompt you a few questions for configuring pi-hole and then you should be done.

Comment: I've an error pls help

Comment: @JITENCHOUDHARY Do what the error says please to see if anything is wrong. ```sudo apt-get update``` NEVER post errors as answers. Post it as a comment right here. Do this in the actual terminal and not with pi-hole please.

Comment: [This](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/error-unable-to-update-package-cache/3230) post might also help. I think it's the same error.

Comment: i try all many times but same error acquired

Comment: Can you help me install the pie hole I tried on Ubuntu 18.04 but I am having this problem on Ubuntu 20.04, I can allow you to install through Team Viewer

Comment: We can setup Team Viewer some time tomorrow if that fits your schedule. I am out of time for today.

Comment: ok i'm free between 12:00 pm to 4:00 pm

Comment: pls send me your schedule

Comment: I am open this afternoon from 2PM until 3 PM CST.

Comment: Where are you from which country

Comment: i am from india

Comment: I am in the US. I think India is like 10.5 hours ahead. That means 22:30-23:30 for you. Oof.

Comment: don't worry i try many times and at the end i crash my all system today . so i install ubuntu 18.04 . would you like to install pi hole on this
would you like to help me.

Comment: how i share you teamviewer codes

Comment: ARE YOU FREE RIGHT NOW

Comment: Sorry. I was doing a workout until now. I'm glad you got it to work.

Comment: [✗] Creating user 'pihole'

Comment: this erroa  what i do